# Angular 4 HttpClient not able to see headers

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, http-headers, angular2-http

I'm trying to get access to the headers in the response, which the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) say I can do by adding `observe: 'response'` to the options on my POST call.

I've done that, but the only header I am able to access is `content-type`, and I need access to 3 custom headers. Here's the code:

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResponse> {

  // this just encodes the data
  let data = this.formEncode({
    username: username,
    password: password
  })

  let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    // i've also tried below, but it didn't work
    // .set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Custom-Header-Name')

  return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(
    ["www.foobar.com", "users", "login"].join("/"),
    data,
    {
      headers: headers,
      observe: 'response'
    }
  )
  .map((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    console.log(res.headers.getAll('Content-Type'))
    console.log(res.headers.getAll('Set-Cookie'))
    console.log(res.headers.getAll('X-Custom-Header-Name'))
    console.log(res.headers.keys())
    return res.body
  })
}
```

I know there are a lot of logs here, and they're all to verify to myself that `content-type` is, in fact, the only response header that I have access to in any of these situations. Also, upon inspection in Chrome or Firefox dev tools, there are headers on the response.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Are there only certain headers that Angular lets you access? Are headers not available in the `map` part of the function?

In other news, the only reason I'm trying to do this at all is because the cookies are not being set properly, but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be an Angular issue.

**Edit:** I've also attempted to use `Http` from `@angular/http`, and get the same results

Comment: Same error here... could you find an solution?

Comment: Sorry for being late, yes! You need the back-end to send the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header with a list of values for headers you want access to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just found the solution, same issue here. I'm running a Node/Express backend, so when configuring the Express app's middlewares (adding CORS support & co), I have to add the following response header:

```
    res.header("access-control-expose-headers",
        +"X-Custom-Header-Name"
        +",Set-Cookie"
        );
```

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155983/angular-4-unable-to-read-headers-from-response-not-a-cors-issue/47156924#47156924) for full config.